# Somatório de campos para input

Tags: php, sql, html5

Bom dia,

Tenho o seguinte:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="campo4">Valor da Peça</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda']">
</div>
```

.
.
    
      Valor da Peça
      
    
.
.
    
      Valor da Peça
      
    
.
.
Dentre outras inputs, mas essas eu preciso somar para inserir em um campo, em que tentei

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="campo6">Valor Total da Venda</label>
  <input ('%.2n', $customer['valor_venda']+$customer['valor_venda2']+$customer['valor_venda3']+$customer['valor_venda4']+$customer['valor_venda5'] . "\n") class="form-control" name="customer['total']" >
  </div>
```

Tentei de várias formas, inclusive, burramente, assim:

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="campo6">Valor Total da Venda</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['total']" value="<?php echo money_format ('%.2n', $customer['valor_venda']+$customer['valor_venda2']+$customer['valor_venda3']+$customer['valor_venda4']+$customer['valor_venda5'] . "\n"); ?>">
</div>
```

---

Estou sem conseguir gravar o valor 'total' no BD (MySQL) e estou sem idéias o que fazer.

Alguma luz, por favor !!

Comment: Marcos você quer que, ao preencher o valor das inputs, o calculo seja feito automaticamente, isso? Ou você está buscando do PHP os valores  quer apenas somar eles e exibir na input?

Comment: e por que um  `. "\n"`no final da soma?

Comment: Sim, que o cálculo seja feito automaticamente e eu possa gravar no campo 'total' do BD.
Com relação ao . "|n", como comentei: "inclusive, burramente..." rsrsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é uma idéia :)

```js
function calcular() {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var num3 = Number(document.getElementById("num3").value);
    var num4 = Number(document.getElementById("num4").value);
    var num5 = Number(document.getElementById("num5").value);
    document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5).toFixed(2);

   }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="campo4">Valor da Peça</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda']" id="num1" onblur="calcular();" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda2']" id="num2" onblur="calcular();" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda3']" id="num3" onblur="calcular();" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda4']" id="num4" onblur="calcular();" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda5']" id="num5" onblur="calcular();" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="campo6">Valor Total da Venda</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" name="total" >
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Ao invés do evento onblur (que é disparado quando o input perde o foco) você pode utilizar o evento onkeyup para que o cálculo ocorra em tempo de digitação.

Comment: Sem sucesso com o onblur e com o onkeyup 
O campo na gravação do BD é zerado
Ele até dá o display no campo total ao adicionar as peças com valor, mas não grava no BD.

Comment: Então o erro deve estar no seu php ou sql pois aqui testei e está gravando no banco do servidor

Comment: Erro meu: Assim funcionou --       <input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" name="customer['total']">

Comment: Grato pela grande ajuda !!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um loop na variável `$customer` e somar cada valor.

```
$soma = 0;
foreach($customer as $valor){
   $soma = $soma + $valor;
}
```

Esse código irá percorrer todos os dados do seu Array e somar tudo na variável `$soma`. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ou fazer `$soma += $valor;`

Comment: Boa! Dessa forma é melhor mesmo!

Comment: A questão é que tenho que somar 5 campos: valor_venda, valor_venda2, valor_venda3, valor_venda4 valor_venda5 para gravar no total.

Não posso dar um loop na variável $customer pois a uso em diversos campos e os campos valores são diferentes.

Comment: <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="campo2">Produto 3</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['produto3']">
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="campo3">Serial</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['serial3']">
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="campo4">Valor da Peça</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['valor_venda3']" id="num3" onkeyup ="calcular();" />
    </div>
  </div>